# Initialize a constant variable and assert if failed (c++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to initialize const variable with a value from map, and want to assert if the map do not contains such a value.

Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

I hoped that c++ `ternary operator ?:` will help me with this but this code doesn't work as  `ternary operator` wants to has same type at both sides.

```
const auto it = modeMap.find(key);
const Mode myMode = (it != modeMap.end()) ? myMode = it->second : assert(false && "Mode doesn't exist");
```

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'const
>   Mode'

Comment: You can't do this with a ternary operator as the ternary operator requires both branches return the same type.

Comment: Yes I know :) So is there an elegant solution for this case?

Comment: `assert` is pretty severe. Would you be OK with an exception?

Comment: Using `assert` is not good for runtime checks. First of all it will abort the program and it will look like a crash, which is no good in any kind of program used by others. Secondly, it's a debug-only *macro*, if you create a release build the assert macro is replaced by empty space.

Comment: @juanchopanza No I don't want use exception.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I know but for my case assert is enough.

Comment: @TM Then you could do the work in a function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: As long as you remember that it's really a macro, and that it will be replaced with blank space in release builds (which might cause syntax errors depending on where you use it).

Comment: What if to do like this?         assert(it != modeMap.end() && "Mode doesn't exist");
        const Mode mode2 = it->second;

Comment: What should happen in the production case with assert disabled if the value is not in the map? I think you should either throw an exception, or terminate your program.

Comment: This code is reading from file which should not be changed at production stage.

Comment: Yes, what should your program do if the would trigger in production? Right now, it could do anything, probably produce a random result. In the best case, it will crash. Why not terminate the program with an error message? That would be defensive programming.

Comment: @Jens I agree with you, for best practices it should done like you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to trade the `assert` for raising an exception (probably a good idea anyway), you could simplify your code by calling [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at):

```
const Mode myMode = modeMap.at(key);
```

This will raise `std::out_of_range` if `key` is not in the map. If you really really need to `assert`, then you could wrap the logic in a function:

```
const Mode& find_or_assert(const std::map<Key, Mode>& modeMap, const Key& key)
{
  auto it = modeMap.find(key);
  assert(it != modeMap.end());
  return it->second;
}
```

then

```
const Mode myMode = find_or_assert(modeMap, key);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `assert` part is reached, `myMode` could not be initialized because `assert` returns nothing (`void`). You could fix this by using the comma operator:

```
const Mode myMode =
(it != modeMap.end()) ? myMode = it->second : (assert(false && "Mode doesn't exist"), SOME_VALUE);
```

to initialize `myMode` with `SOME_VALUE` on execution of `assert`.

Anyway, your use of `assert` seems invalid. [Look up](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) how to use it properly.

Comment: `static_assert` wouldn't be much help in testing a runtime condition.

Comment: @cad Thanks for link!

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is that of @juanchopanza, however if you want to `assert` and not throw an exception:

In my humble opinion it would be better to define a function for this job as follows:

```
const auto it = modeMap.find(key);

Mode& assert_value_exists(std::map<Key_Type, Mode> const& map_, Key_Type const& key) {
  auto it = map_.find(key);
  assert(it != map_.end());
  return it->second;
}
```

Comment: That dereferences map::end() if the key is not in the map which is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see any changes. You still use `it->second` when it is `end()`.

Comment: @Jens if `it == map_.end()` `assert` will be fired so return won't be reached.

Comment: Only if not compiled with NDEBUG. The question looks more like this should not be an assert at all, but a real runtime-check which terminates the program with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is equivalent to my target. Which is initialize const variable when key exist in the map and rise assertion otherwise.

```
const auto it = modeMap.find(key);
assert(it != modeMap.end() && "Mode doesn't exist");
const Mode myMode = it->second;
```

I agree with all answers here that the assertion by itself is not a good solution. And it is dangerous in the production case when assert disabled and the value is not in the map. And as [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169853/jens) mention it is better to throw an exception, or terminate your program. (So other answers recommend).

Please do not consider this answer as a best way from point of defensive programming view.

This is an answer to a question to initialize const variable with a value from map, and rise assert if the map do not contains such a key.

**EDITED:** As [@cad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494013/cad) mentioned by pointing the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/)

> Assert macro is designed to capture programming errors, not user or run-time errors, since it is generally disabled after a program exits its debugging phase.

**EDITED:** Also want to quote @[Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg)

> " Using assert is not good for runtime checks. First of all it will
>   abort the program and it will look like a crash, which is no good in
>   any kind of program used by others. Secondly, it's a debug-only macro,
>   if you create a release build the assert macro is replaced by empty
>   space. As long as you remember that it's really a macro, and that it
>   will be replaced with blank space in release builds (which might cause
>   syntax errors depending on where you use it). "